Reading argc value in ARM64 assembly
I'm trying to read argc value in my aarch64 assembly program. I know that it should be stored in x0 register, with argv being in x1. When I tried to debug this with GDB I found out that depending on how I compile my code x0 folds different values at start, but never argc value.
My code:
.global _start

.section .text
_start:

    cmp x0, #0x2
    bne end_argv

    b good_end

end_argv:
    mov x8, #0x5d
    mov x0, #0x1
    svc 0

good_end:
    mov x8, #0x5d
    mov x0, #0x0
    svc 0


When compiled using this commands:
as code.s -o code.o
ld code.o -o code.elf

All registers, according to GDB, fold 0 as values, including x0 and x1.
When compiled using GCC:
gcc code.s -o code.elf -nostdlib -g -nostartfiles

at start x0 and x1 always have the same values, respectively 0x7ff7fc7180 and 0x7ff7fff940.
GDB register values at start of program after compiling with GCC.

argc is in x0 only if you use the C library and main. Not with -nostdlib and _start in which case argc should be the topmost item on the stack.
